# How to root MicromaxA116 running on CM11

Tags: micromax

My phone is Micromax A116, have installed CM11 ROM, but this phone is now showing your phone is not rooted, I am not able to root phone by previous softwares which are for Jelly Bean

Comment: Flash SuperSU through the custom recovery.

Answer (score 4):

Since you already have a custom ROM, you can do either of 2 things:

**1. Enable native root:**

1. Enable "Developer Options" (tap on "Build Number" 7 times under "About Phone").
2. In Developer Options, find the "Root Access" item and tap on it, and choose an option other than "Disabled", such as "Apps" or "Apps and ADB".

**2. Use SuperSU:**

1. Download the latest SuperSU flashable zip from the developer's [website](https://download.chainfire.eu/740/supersu/).
2. Go into whatever custom recovery you are using, and flash it like you did the custom ROM you use.

Both will work, but I prefer SuperSU as that gives more granular control over apps and logging, not to mention a better UI.

**WARNING:**

**DO NOT** enable both at the same time to avoid conflicts. Use only one or the other.